# Render form partial from view ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, partial

Im trying to render a form from another controller in my view.

This is posts_index, and the render post.comments works fine, but the form for a new comment doesnt.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    <%= simple_format post.text %>
      <%= render post.comments.order('created_at DESC').all %>
      <%= render :partial => '/comments/form', locals: {post: post} %>
```

I get this error: undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

The comments form:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Comment %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "comment_text_box" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I understand I need to pass the post.comments to the form, but can't figure out how.

Post_show works with `<%= render "comments/form" %>`

Post and comments are a `has_many` relationship, posts `has_many` comments.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: can you add full stack error trace

Comment: You don't have @post because you're looping through the posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass variables into your partial like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  <%= simple_format post.text %>
  <%= render post.comments.order('created_at DESC').all %>
  <%= render partial: '/comments/form', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```

and change your form partial to this:

```
<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  // form fields
<% end %>
```

Comment: So i just tried this, and now im getting:  
undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007ffa5378fa00>:0x007ffa5435c978>

Comment: @user2891803 did you pass post variable in partial?

Comment: @user2891803 try updated answer. If it doesn't work then can you post full error message and on which line do you get this error?

Comment: I tried again, the error is one line 1:
undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007ffa5378fa00>:0x007ffa53eef9a8>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for([post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
....

Comment: If it helps, the code you provided works in the post_show page.

Comment: @user2891803 Strange because we are passing post variable in partial by `locals: {post: post}`. May be browser is caching it. Can you restart server or try it in different browser? What is the difference between post_show page?

Comment: scratch that, it doesnt work on show page, unless i change post back to `@post`... and in the comments create, i have: `@post = Post.find(params(:post_id))`

Comment: @user2891803 can you edit your question and post posts index view the way it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62531/discussion-between-mandeep-and-user2891803).

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for the partial, you need to send it the post it's related to.  It would look like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    <%= simple_format post.text %>
      <%= render post.comments.order('created_at DESC').all %>
      <%= render :partial => '/comments/form', post: post%>
```

Comment: I tried this, after reading some other SO questions, and couldnt get it to work.  It gives me the same error.